# JRebel not starting with Liberty Server, Mac, Eclipse Luna, Java 8 runtime

Tags: java, jrebel

Jrebel is not working with the following configuration: Mac OSX Yosemite, Eclipse Luna, Java 8 runtime.  I changed my runtime in Eclipse to Java 6 but in the jrebel log it looks like it is still using the Java 8 runtime.  Is there a way change that.  So when I start my liberty server, I do not see the JRebel banner message at server startup.

JRebel for Eclipse 6.2.5.RELEASE-201509301022

I see this over and over again in the jrebel log:

```
2015-10-09 11:53:16.737 [rebel.lssr] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Started java.lang.UNIXProcess@47acc7c
2015-10-09 11:53:17.164 [rebel.lssr] DEBUG o.z.exec.WaitForProcess - java.lang.UNIXProcess@47acc7c stopped with exit code 0 
2015-10-09 11:54:17.169 [rebel.lssr] DEBUG EclipseJRebelClientAdapter - JVMUtil.findJavaExecutable() vmInstallLocation=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
2015-10-09 11:54:17.169 [rebel.lssr] DEBUG EclipseJRebelClientAdapter - JVMUtil.findJavaExecutable() vmInstallLocation=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
2015-10-09 11:54:17.170 [rebel.lssr] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Executing [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java, -Drebel.log=false, -Drebel.log.stdout=false, -Drebel.env.ide=Eclipse, -Drebel.env.ide.product=Eclipse, -Drebel.env.ide.version=4.4.2, -Drebel.env.ide.plugin.version=6.2.5.RELEASE-201509301022, -Drebel.properties=/Users/USER/.jrebel/jrebel.properties, -Drebel.license_server.legacy=false, -Drebel.base=/Users/USER/.jrebel, -Drebel.open_browser=true, -Drebel.log.licensing=true, -cp, /Users/USER/Desktop/Downloadsmain/eclipse/plugins/org.zeroturnaround.eclipse.embedder_6.2.5.RELEASE-201509301022/jrebel/jrebel.jar, com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.CLILicensingAPIImpl, reserveSeat, , ]...
2015-10-09 11:54:17.172 [rebel.lssr] DEBUG o.z.exec.ProcessExecutor - Started java.lang.UNIXProcess@2f6bab81
2015-10-09 11:54:17.929 [rebel.lssr] DEBUG o.z.exec.WaitForProcess - java.lang.UNIXProcess@2f6bab81 stopped with exit code 0
```

Comment: Care to report it to the official support forum? http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/forum/jrebel/

Comment: Can you paste the application details including java classes?

Comment: It is a spring based web application, very basic that I just created with initial setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with Java8 nicely so there shouldn't be a need to switch to Java6. And Java8 is faster.

How do you **start** your server? If you open Help > JRebel Configuration > Startup, then you can find three different ways:

1. "IDE" where JRebel plugin will set up the server automatically. This requires you to configure the server inside Eclipse but it's smoothest to develop locally.
2. "CLI" where you can adjust a few things in local server startup script. Although, this one has the downside that scripts need updating whenever you upgrade JRebel.
3. "Remote Server" when you don't want to run the app in your own machine but rather let it run on a server in your network. Or even in the cloud.

Comment: "IDE" where JRebel plugin will set up the server automatically. This requires you to configure the server inside Eclipse but it's smoothest to develop locally.  I configured it through the IDE.

Comment: Do you see JRebel banner in server console output? If yes, then you should also see "will be monitored" statement which shows which directory JRebel is monitoring. After you change and compile any class, you should see "Reloading class" in server console.